# Can we create multiple windows containers which can be used as VSTS build agents from individual Windows Server VM?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, azure-devops, windows-server-2016, build-agent

**Problem:** To reduce maintenance of overgrowing VM's which we are currently using as build agents in VSTS.

**Idea to resolve :** We are thinking of using multiple docker windows containers created from indivdual windows server VM's as VSTS build agents.Therefore we want these containers to be part of VSTS Build Agent pool .

Can we create multiple windows containers which can be used as VSTS build agents from individual Windows Server VM ?

Comment: how does VSTS agent connect to the VM?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible to install build agents in docker windows containers.
The main steps as:

> - Set up a Docker host
> - Create a Docker image with the Visual Studio
>   Build Agent inside
> - Run the Docker container and automatically start
>   the agent

For details you can refer [Running a VS Team Services (VSO) Build Agent in a Windows Docker Container](https://roadtoalm.com/2016/02/15/running-a-vs-team-services-vso-build-agent-in-a-windows-docker-container/).

Answer (score 0):

I can see some windows images in the [VSTS Agent Docker](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker) repo. You can try them out.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/blob/windows/windows/servercore/10.0.14393/Dockerfile